# How to make my plugin contributes adding a menu-item into an existing sub-menu from an existing menu in Eclipse platform?

Tags: java, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, menuitem

Currently I'm working in an Eclipse plug-in project where I have created a View which could be displayed by clicking on main menu ***Window->Show view->Other...***, then clicking on my View from the ***Other*** category.

Currently I'm trying this in my `plugin.xml` file:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution
        locationURI="menu:window?after=additions">

     <menu 
           id="com.kwantec.helloworld.menus.sampleMenu"
           label="Sample Menu"
           mnemonic="M">
        <command
              commandId="com.kwantec.helloworld.commands.sampleCommand"
              id="com.kwantec.helloworld.menus.sampleCommand"
              mnemonic="S">
        </command>
     </menu>
  </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

..that causes a new sub-menu `Sample Menu` appears into the existing `Window` menu of Eclipse. Then I can open my *View* by clicking on `Window->Sample Menu->Sample Command`.
But now, what I need it's to directly add that `Sample Command` into *menu-items* of *sub-menu* `Show View` from existing `Window` menu of Eclipse.
Something like `Window->Show View->Sample Command`.

I have spent several days looking into Eclipse Platform documentation without significant advance. 
Does anybody knows how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views shown directly in 'Window > Show Views' are known as 'view shortcuts'. You add these for a particular perspective using the `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` extension point.

Something like:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions"> 
    <perspectiveExtension 
        targetID="org.eclipse.ui.resourcePerspective"> 
        <viewShortcut id="your.view.id"/> 
    </perspectiveExtension> 
</extension>
```

Herer `targetID` defines the perspective you are updating and the `id` of `viewShortcut` is the id of your view.

You may need to reset the perspective to get your addition to show (Window > Perspective > Reset Perspective).

Comment: Thanks so much greg-449 !! That's exactly what I was looking for. It works perfectly!